# direct access to Textbox returns undefined values

Tags: javascript, html

I have a weird problem. In my js file, if I access a textbox directly like `txtbox1.value` it returns `undefined`, while if I get it with `document.getElementById('txtbox1').value` it gives me the value. I am not sure why this is happening. Can you suggest me some thing, where should I look?

Is this something related to IE 8?

Comment: No thats what you have to do. Theres no way to get the value just by txtbox1.value. It doesnt know thats what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `txtbox1`, you are accessing a (probably) global variable of that name, which does not necessarily have anything to do with the HTML element with id `txtbox1`.

When you use `document.getElementById('txtbox1')`, you are specifically looking up the HTML element with id `txtbox1`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add `id = 'txtbox1'` in your textbox tag

Comment: if it is not already added, how `document.getElementById('txtbox1').value` gives the value?